# Laravel inserting into 2 tables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i have 2 tables `user` and `tn_user`, table `user` is a table containing information to log in, i made it by tutorial from https://laravel.com/ so basically it was automatically created, while `tn_user` is a table that i make by myself

> USER TABLE
>   [image: image alt]
>   in case u can't see the atribut are `id`, `name`, `email`, `password` that the important things, `email` and `password` in this table is used to logging in
>
> TN_USER TABLE
>   [image: image alt]
>   the atribut are `cn_id`, `cv_name`, `cv_email`, `cn_phone`, `cv_position`, `cv_address`, `cv_country`, `cv_username`, `cv_password`, `cv_privileges`, those are the important thing

based on the form below i want to insert `username` and `password` into table `user` and the rest into table `tn_user` and how do i do that? im pretty new to laravel so not really quite understand how, usually i use CI

[image: image alt]

> **UserController.php**
>   this is where the code i use to insert data
>   i use json response to parse the data and not quite sure how to insert data into 2 tables little help here

```php
public function createOrEdit(){
    //get current user
    $currentUserId = Auth::user()->id;

    $isUpdate = false;
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $user = new UserCompany;
    if($id != ""){
        $user = UserCompany::where('cn_id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
        $user->cv_updated_by = $currentUserId;
        $user->cv_updated_at = Carbon::now();
        $isUpdate = true;
    }else{
        $user->cv_created_by = $currentUserId;
        $user->cv_created_at = Carbon::now();
    }
    $user->cv_name = Input::get('name');
    $user->cv_position = Input::get('position');
    $user->cv_email = Input::get('email');
    $user->cn_phone = Input::get('phone');
    $user->cv_address = Input::get('address');
    $user->cv_username = Input::get('username');
    $user->cv_password = Input::get('password');
    $user->cv_country = Input::get('country');

    if($isUpdate){
        UserCompany::where('cn_id','=',$id)->update(['cv_updated_by' => $user->cv_updated_by,
            'cv_updated_at' => $user->cv_updated_at,
            'cv_name' => $user->cv_name,
            'cv_position' => $user->cv_position,
            'cv_email' => $user->cv_email,
            'cn_phone' => $user->cn_phone,
            'cv_country' => $user->cv_country,
            'cv_username' => $user->cv_username,
            'cv_password' => $user->cv_password,
            'cv_address' => $user->cv_address]);

    }else{
        $user->save();
    }

    $returnedData = UserCompany::all();

    $response = array(
            'content' => $returnedData,
            'status' => 'success',
        );

    return Response::json($response);
}
```

> **UserCompany.php** is my model but since im new im not really understand how to use relationship yet

```php
 <?php namespace Activity;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserCompany extends Model {
    protected $table = 'tn_user';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [

    ];

    /*public function usercompany(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Activity\user');
    }*/
}
```

Comment: How do you keep relationship between two tables? what is the foreign key?

Comment: hmm you've got the point bout that, i'm still think about it

Comment: i change few attributes, at `user` table `id` i changed it into `id_user` and then in `tn_user` i add another field name `id_user`, so the foreign key is `id_user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that in the `UserCompany` class, by setting the `fillable`, It means you are setting table column which you want to alter, in this case `tn_user` table. So this means, by setting

```
protected $fillable = [];
```

It means, that you are making no table columns should undergo modification when you are using commands like;

```
$user_details->cv_name = Input::get('cv_name');
```

Okay, so the first thing that you should know is that when creating two tables i.e `users` and `tn_users` you should have a column which carries a value which relate the two tables, I suggest that you are to user `id` from the `users` table:

I have noticed that you have used `cn_id` to be a linker, but it is best if every table has its own incrementing id column and also in this case, its own link_id column

Let's say you are starting over:

1. Open the **command prompt** or **Terminal** and go to you laravel project folder directory and type: `-$ php artisan make:model User -m` and again `-$ php artisan make:model UserDetail -m`

   What this will do is, create `User` and `UserDetail`, and adding the -m means its creating the migrations for the models associated which is `create_users_table` and `create_user_details_table`
2. From the `create_users_table` simply create the desired table columns as shown below:

---

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;   

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('auth');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('online');
            $table->string('lang', 2);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }    
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Now for the `create_tn_users_table` its kinda important, you should set which links with the users account so that suppose you delete the users, his credentials are also removed, but you can make it do otherwise if you want.

---

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTnUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tn_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->integer('link_user_id')
                ->references('id')->on('users');   // Relationship btn table tn_users and users
            $table->string('phone');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('tn_users');
    }
}
```

Now go the **command prompt** or **terminal** and type `-$ php artisan migrate` to have the tables created.

Again on the **command prompt** or **terminal** type `-$ php artisan make:controller UserController --resource` and have the controller made together with its resources.

On the `create()` function inside the UserController, add the `Request` in as a parameter.

The functions is to be reached upon the submission of the form that you have created

---

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\TnUser;
use ...

class UserController extends Controller{
    public function create(Request $request){
         $tn_user = new TnUser();
         $user = new User();
         $user->username = $request['username'];
         $user->password = bcrypt($request['username']);
         ...
         $user->save();
         $tn_user->full_name = ucword(strtolower($request['full_name'));
         $tn_user->link_user_id = $user->id;   // uses the previously save id
         $tn_user->phone = trim($request['phone']);
         $th_user->save();
    }
}
```

I hope I have answered you questions. Here are some helpful links to learn.

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#creating-columns
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests

Answer (score 1):

You Create 2 objects

```
$user = new User()
$user->username = INPUT::get('username');
$user->password = $password // Hashed
$user->save();
$user_detail = new UserCompany() // Your detail table modal.
$user_detail->cv_name = Input::get('cv_name');
//etc
$user_detail->save()
```

Comment: how about relationship in my model?